# How to loop through the index of xpaths from a json file?

Tags: python, json, xpath

Say I have an `xpath` in JSON like this:

```
{
  "xpath": "[@id='idname']/div/[1]"
}
```

I need to loop through it so I can increment the index and get:

```
//*[@id='idname']/div/[1]
//*[@id='idname']/div/[2]
//*[@id='idname']/div/[3]
...
```

How do I use it in a loop? I tried changing the `xpath` to an f-string

```
{
  "xpath": "f'//*[@id=\'idname\']/div/[{each}]\'"
}
```

and looping through it with

```
for each in range(1,5):
    xpath
```

but I get an error that it's an invalid `xpath` expression.

Hope someone could help, thanks!

Edit:

Sorry about the xpath confusion. I'm aware the one in my example is invalid, I just put it like that for simplicity's sake. I just wanted to loop through the indices in xpaths and SP Sharan provided a solution

Comment: That expression `[@id='idname']/div/[1]` is not a valid XPath 1 or 2 or 3.0 expression. Are you sure you don't want or have `[@id='idname']/div[1]`? In XPath 3.1, `[@id='idname']/div/[1]` is valid but constructs an XPath 3.1 array with an integer number in it in the last step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use python's `.format()` to insert the text you want at the position you have earlier mentioned using curly brackets.

```py
import json

with open("xpath.json") as f:
    data = json.load(f)

xpath = data["xpath"]

for i in range(5):
    print("//*" + xpath.format(index=i))
```

The JSON file I used

```json
{
  "xpath": "[@id='idname']/div/[{index}]"
}
```

Output:

```
//*[@id='idname']/div/[0]
//*[@id='idname']/div/[1]
//*[@id='idname']/div/[2]
//*[@id='idname']/div/[3]
//*[@id='idname']/div/[4]
```

Comment: But the output strings are still invalid XPath expressions.